# background-size:contain doesn't work

Tags: css, background-size

I am stuck trying to get this site's logo to resize automatically smaller as the device width gets smaller. Seems like it should:

```
.imageset.site_logo {
background-image: url("./images/logo.png");
padding-left: 372px;
padding-top: 120px;
background-size:contain;}
```

You can see it here: http://www.mybetforum.com/

Comment: The `background-size:contain` works as it is supposed to. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I expect as I reduce screen width it would reduce size to match the height of the container containing quick links.

Comment: Your problem lies with the `position: absolute` of `#page-header.page-header-metro .headerbar`, defined in `metro.css` at line `333`. Change that to relative, add `display: block` to your `span` and it will behave like you expect it to.

Comment: Why do you have it as a background image? If you create an img element it will push the content down and be easier to size.

Comment: No it won't, @Tom. It's placed in an absolute positioned element.

Comment: Yes it is working as it should, you'reimplementation is incorrect. I would refactor everything within the .headerbar as you are making use of a lot of unnecessary floats and absolute positioning which will only give you problems with different screen sizes

Comment: Yeah, obviously the position: absolute should be removed.

Comment: This is a commercial phpBB style. It's hard to refactor the whole style.

Comment: @Mark, if you expect an absolute positioned element to behave like it's displayed in the normal flow of the document, you are simply in the wrong. You should change the position of its absolute positioned parent to `relative` and then work out the height and width of your element. As a side note, usually `backgorund-image` is used together with `width` and `height` (to control size, hence responsiveness), not with paddings.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a simple fix. I may throw this back on the style designer. I could also substitute smaller images of the logo at various screen widths.

Comment: @Mark, did you try `max-width` property?

Comment: No. Where would this be used?